# How to handle the item of a ListView's by viewcell TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with a custom viewcell where I put a Label and GestureRecognizers with it.
How can I handle diferent Item using Label with TapGestureRecognizer. So fare this is my code.

```
<ViewCell>
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
      <Label Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource LettersConverter}}" FontSize="30" TextColor="#edfff1"/>
      <Label Text="&#xf017;" FontSize="40">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>                                    
    </StackLayout>                                
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="1">
      <Label Text="Alarm" TextColor="#edfff1" FontSize="Micro"/>
      <Label Text="{Binding AlarmTime, StringFormat='{0:dddd, d MMMM, yyyy, HH:mm}'}"/>                                    
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Thank you.

Updated Code:

Xaml:

```
<Label Text="&#xf017;">
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer                                                         
                                                        Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Label>
```

Code:

```
ICommand tapCommand;
        public MainPage()
        {
            tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
        }
        public ICommand TapCommand
        {
            get { return tapCommand; }
        }
        void OnTapped(object s)
        {
            test.Text = "Works";            
        }
```

Final working Code.

Xaml:

```
<Label Text="Test">
                                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                        Command="{Binding Path = TapCommand, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                     />
                                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Label>
```

Code behind.

```
ICommand tapCommand;

//constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        tapCommand = new Command(OnClick);
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }

    void OnClick(object i)
    {
        var model = (Note)i;
        st.Text = model.Title;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy.
3 special steps

> 1 Bind the object to your label like this CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
>
> 2 create function to call Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
  <Label Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource LettersConverter}}" FontSize="30" TextColor="#edfff1"/>
  <Label Text="&#xf017;" FontSize="40">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
  </Label>                                    
</StackLayout>
```

> 3  in your code behind get the selected label  var lbl = sender as Label;
>   get the bound model as selected      var selectedItem = lbl.BindingContext as YourModel;

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var lbl = sender as Label;

        var selectedItem = lbl.BindingContext as YourModel;
        if (selectedItem == null) return;
        // now you can access any property of your model
        // for example  var id = YourModel.id

        // or you can pass your model to a function like
        //HideorShowDetail(selectedItem);
    }
```

Note you can use this approach for any object.
 example if you where creating a clickable image in a listView.

```
var lbl = sender as Label; will be var img = sender as Image;
```

`button would be var btn = sender as Button;`
etc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know which Label was clicked. If I were you, I'd use an ICommand instead of the event handler and a CommandParameter which gives you something like an ID for the item.

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnClickCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding ItemId}" />
```

In your ViewModel or code behind (depending on what your `BindingContext` is, you'll need to implement the ICommand like this:

```
ICommand _onClickCommand;

public ICommand OnClickCommand 
{
    get { return _onClickCommand; }
}

public YourViewModel() {
    OnClickCommand = new Command (OnClick);
}

void OnClick(object i) {
    var labelId = Convert.ToString(i);

    // Now you know which label was clicked and you can do something with it
}
```

Xamarin has a good tutorial on how to do something like this on their official documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/).

---

**Edit:** So, this seems to be what you're looking for.

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnClickCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

and then

```
void OnClick(object i) {
    var model = (YourViewModel)i;

    // Now you can access model.AlarmTime, model.Title etc.
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** The problem here is that the TapGestureRecognizer is not pointing to the page's BindingContext. What you have to do is the following:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path = BindingContext.OnClickCommand, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

Also, add x:Name to your Page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App6"
             x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="MainPage"> <!-- x:Reference points here -->
```

Now, when you tap the label, OnClickCommand is found in the main BindingContext, not within your ListView's ItemsSource.

Comment: It's not exactly what I need. I need to listView Item as a parent of clicked label. let say I have 10 items in listView, every each has a label with a TapGestureRecognizer, so when user click on label app need to know which Item from the list should be change/update in database or in listView.

Comment: My thinking was that you might already have an ID field since the database table will also have an ID anyway. However, you can replace the CommandParameter with this `"{Binding .}"` to get the whole object with all the properties you need. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I can't check this code now. I will let you know tomorrow. Regards

Comment: It doesn't work. I followed official documentation as well but some reason nothing happen. If I understand correctly "YourViewModel()" is a constructor for class in code behind, correct?

Comment: @Klick Yes, that's the constructor. Let me quickly try this out on a small sample app.

Comment: @Klick Ok, I figured out the problem. OnClickCommand wasn't pointing to the main BindingContext. I added Edit 2 to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your code finally works for me but after some modifications. Check my other post.

Comment: As you see " BindingContext.OnClickCommand" didn't work for me. Without "BindingContext" works. Thank you one more time for help. Regards